# Can you access a client's bookmarks using javascript with their permission?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, bookmarks

I want to make it easier for a user to import bookmarks to my server. Is there anyway to automate this process using javascript to obtain the user's bookmarks? I'm assuming the browser has to have this feature - and I'm not sure if any browser does due to the inherent security risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible for ***security/privacy reasons***. The only way is to ask them *explicitly* through form input to give you but I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: IE6 had a way (window.external.ImportExportFavorites) to trigger an upload of the favorites to a server with the user's permission but that method was neutered in IE6 on XPSP2 and never was reenabled.

Answer (score 2):

The browser is obviously aware of their bookmarks, but no, JS cannot access this information - it would be leaking private data as you yourself have noted.

Anything you can do in JS with the user's permission can be done without their permission. The only manual control they have is "Run scripts" or "Don't".

Answer (score 2):

As yourself and others have noted, it's not possible because of privacy and security implications.

What you can do however is to import bookmarks from a source (XML, JSON, HTML...). Most browsers have an export bookmarks feature that generates a file. You can parse that to get what you want.

Comment: +1: If users want to submit their bookmarks to a site for backup or whatever purpose, exporting them using the browser functionality to do so, then uploading the resulting file is the best way. Not automated, as it will require some action on the users part, but at least a solution is presented.

Answer (score 0):

What Sarfraz said, and thank God for it. I don't think users want people on the web to be able to access their bookmarks for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

im a 100 % sure there is no way to do this in js due to the securtity risk, however its probably possible with activex but thats only available on internet explorer